# Will a Toto Eco-Drake toilet with a 12" rough-in fit my 10.75" rough-in?

Tags: toilet, rough-in

My bathroom has a 10 3/4" rough-in and the currently-installed toilet needs to be replaced. Some research has let me to learn that the Toto Eco-Drake line of toilets that specify 12" rough-ins can be installed with as little as a little under 11". I have 10 3/4" available to work with. Does anybody know if I have enough space? If I'd come up like 1/8" too short, is there any way to move the unit forward or tilt the tank or something by the minuscule amount necessary to make it fit?

Comment: I could have bought new toilet and taken 100 craps before you made up your decision on this.  Get a 10" tank and save yourself hours of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have seen, but the Eco-Drake comes in a 10" RI too. Here is the [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003H785T6)

The 12 inch model seems like it may not do it for you. From the looks of the PDF spec sheet it only allows 3/4" space behind the tank as it is.

Comment: I have seen this, but it's only elongated, and I'm potty-training a kid and have heard that round is better. And I already have a nice round potty training seat.

Comment: If I recall properly, the 10" R.I. are available in round for much less. I did a fast search but could not find one though. The Toto site may do something for you.

Comment: No 10" rough-in round Drake. I ended up getting the elongated one.

Answer (score 0):

There exists an ***offset toilet flange***.  Depending on the access you have to the plumbing below the toilet, and its nature (PVC good, cast-iron not so much) you may be able to shift the toilet location the amount you need.

[image: One example from a Google search]

Comment: Cast iron in a concrete slab, unfortunately.